# Как убрать обертку обзаца для iframe в wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Можно ли как-то сделать так что бы тег `iframe` не оборачивался в тег `p` в теле статьи? 
Я хочу ограничить ширину текста в 800 пикселей, но при этом чтобы картинки и видео были на 100%. Если я ограничиваю тег `p {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;}` получается что текст выравнивается по центру и изображения остаются растянуты на 100% но видео тоже сжимается на 800 пикселей, так как оно оборачивается в тег `p` автоматически.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл `functions.php` вашей темы следующий код:

```
function strip_ptags_on_iframe($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe.*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'strip_ptags_on_iframe');
```

Этот код автоматически будет резать теги `p` вокруг `iframe`. Аналогично можно обрезать `p` вокруг других тегов, например `object`, `img`, `script` и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно!

Comment: Вероятно вы знаете, ест еще такая проблема, когда я залогинен как автор я почему-то не могу опубликовать iframe, когда как админ все нормально, я помещаю iframe в тело статьи публикую, перехожу по ссылке и вижу видео в теле статьи, но когда я делаю пост автором и добавляю iframe и после публикации в теле статьи есть все кроме iframe он его почему-то вырезает, может это в теме проблема?

Comment: @AntonEssential, Если вкратце, то нужно добавить тег в разрешённые и сделать это можно так: `add_action( 'init', function () {global $allowedtags; $allowedtags['iframe'] = array('src'    => array(), 'height' => array(), 'width'  => array());} );`.